# Are probabilities / expected times of transition between any two states within an irreducible class same?

Tags: stochastic-processes

In a discrete time Markov chain, consider an irreducible/communicating class,

1. Are the probabilities of ever
   transition between any two states
   within the class the same?

   If the class is recurrent, the
   probabilities of each state ever
   transitioning back to itself are
   always 1 and thus the same. Here I
   wonder about the general case for
   transition between any two states
   or/and the class may not be
   recurrent.
2. Are the expected times of transition
   between any two states within the
   class the same?

   If the class is transient or null
   positive, the expected times of each
   state transitioning back to itself
   are always $\infty$  and thus the
   same. Here I wonder about the
   general case for transition between
   any two states or/and the class may
   not be transient or null positive.

If the answers are no, are there some other cases where the probabilities/expected times are the same for all the transitions between any two states in an irreducible class?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know, examples and counterexamples can be great... So, you might want to check this conjecture, and future ones, on your favorite collection of basic cases. Here, two of the simplest examples are enough to demolish (or at least, to restrict severely the scope of) your questions.

In (1), you think *transient*, so consider a nearest neighbour random walk on the integer line with probabilities $p$ for $+1$ jumps and $1-p$ for $-1$ jumps, with $p\ne1/2$ (and if you think *null recurrent*, take $p=1/2$.)

In (2), you think *positive recurrent*, so consider a nearest neighbour random walk on a discrete circle with probabilities $p$ for clockwise jumps and $1-p$ for anticlockwise jumps.

If periodicity is at stake, replace everywhere $1-p$ by $1-p-q$ and add jumps from any vertex to itself with probability $q$.

Finally, if you think *positive recurrent* but on an infinite state space, nearest neighbour random walks on a discrete halfline with a drift towards the origin are your friend.